# In Google play, what kind of apps can have no icon after installing?

Tags: android, icons

My friend wants to develop a app called Magazine,  users can view beautiful pictures after screen is locked as attached. That means users can not use it after unlocking screen. I have to hide its icon on desk, otherwise it cannot load normally when users press it after unlocking screen.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Manifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".view.ActivityMain"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The `<intent-filter>` parts is what adds the app's `Activity` onto the homescreen.

More specifically:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

So if you remove that from the Activity, the app won't show an icon within the Homescreen Launcher.

However, since without an Activity for your app, it becomes a bit harder for users to configure your app. So a lot of developers would still create a Settings Activity for users to modify settings.

Answer (score 0):

in android and iphone all applications need to have an icon. You can not hide it either. What you can do is keep that application and that inside have some minimum configuration for the unlock screen that you want to make and thus achieve a more personalized experience for the user

Comment: Icon wont appear  if you are removing `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` filter from main activity. So it's possible to hide the icon.